# Calculating minimum and maximum values of a histogram

Tags: c#, histogram, emgucv, gdal

I have an image that is grayscale (has a single band) with values ranging from -182 to 94. However, for the most part, the histogram of the image occupies just a narrow range as shown in the diagram below. I have the values of the pixels in an array. I want to find the start and end of the histogram (in this case around 22 to 70). Is there any built in function that I can use to do that? 
I am using C#, Emgu CV and GDAL

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code showing how you can access values. Note that start and end must be defined by some condition, after all, obviously the real start/end is -182 to 94. What makes around 22 special to you? What if you had two peaks in the histogram?

Comment: NetMage I have the values in an array, so to access them, I simply index them. I do agree that the start and end mush be defined by some condition. I am trying to separate the real start/end from the histograms start and end. 22 is special because that is where the Histogram starts from.

Comment: So the array is indexed from 0 - end or from -182 to 94 ? How do you know it starts at -182? What does "starts from" mean? Are all the values in the array before `hist[22]` equal to zero? What is the hist value at -182?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your histogram values are in an `int[]` called `hist`, you can use some LINQ extension methods to find the largest contiguous group of values, and find their start and end positions in the array. This is overkill if your histogram simply has all zeros with one non-zero area, and does not handle multiple non-zero areas very well - it just picks the longest horizontal span.

```
var histPos = hist
                .Select((hval, pos) => new { hval, pos })
                .GroupByWhile((prev,cur) => prev.hval != 0 && cur.hval != 0)
                .MaxBy(zvg => zvg.Count())
                .Select(zvg => zvg.pos);
var start = histPos.Min();
var end = histPos.Max();
```

The extension methods I used are `GroupByWhile` which groups sequential objects as long as a boolean lambda returns true, and `MaxBy` which returns the object that has the largest return value from a lambda.

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    // TKey combineFn((TKey Key, T Value) PrevKeyItem, T curItem):
    // PrevKeyItem.Key = Previous Key
    // PrevKeyItem.Value = Previous Item
    // curItem = Current Item
    // returns new Key
    public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combineFn) {
        using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (srce.MoveNext()) {
                var prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

                while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return prevkv;
                    prevkv = (combineFn(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
                }
                yield return prevkv;
            }
        }
    }

        // bool testFn(T prevItem, T curItem)
    // returns groups by sequential matching bool
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupByWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> testFn) =>
        src.ScanPair(1, (kvp, cur) => testFn(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1)
           .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

    public static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, Comparer<TKey> keyComparer) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => keyComparer.Compare(keySelector(a), keySelector(b)) > 0 ? a : b);
    public static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keySelector) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(keySelector(a), keySelector(b)) > 0 ? a : b);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can pixels as an sbyte array,
in which case this works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleMinMax
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sbyte[] array1 = { 1, -1, -2, 0, 99, -111 };

            MinMax(array1);

            void MinMax(sbyte[] array)
            {
                // Report minimum and maximum values.
                Console.WriteLine("max = {0}; min = {1}", array.Max(), array.Min());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just finding the maximum and minimum in an array. I want to separate the histogram start/end points from the real start/end points.